# My html bootstrap sidebar item just won't drop down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

Currently trying to create a simple dropdown sidebar using bootstrap.
Below is my code in html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sidebar</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="common.css"/> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="row"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Item 1</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Item 1A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 1B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 1C</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="row"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Item 2</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2B</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
```

Here is my common.css:

```
.row{
background-color:#ffff99;
border:2px solid black;
}
```

The sidebar won't drop down when I click Item 1 or Item 2. Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the basic template on the Bootstrap site

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

At the bottom of the HTML block they have referenced two javascript files which you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the jquery.js and bootstrap.js.

Answer (score 0):

The dropdowns work with JavaScript, so you need to include that. Try to add `bootstrap.min.js` to your application by adding

```
<script src="bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to the head section of your page, or just before the closing `</body>`-tag of the page.

Additionally, you need to add jQuery, which is done the same way, but make sure you include it before the bootstrap script.

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdowns work with JavaScript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .row {
            background-color: #ffff99;
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="row">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Item 1</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Item 1A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 1B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 1C</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="row">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Item 2</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2B</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```